# CSS Permutation Class Selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Is there any way to have a selector depending on any permutation of multiple classes?

For instance:

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside">
       text
    </div>
</div>

<div class="inside">
    <div class="outside">
       text
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there a single selector that would make both text blue?
Currently, I can only achieve this with two selectors:

```
.inside .outside {color: blue;}
.outside .inside {color: blue;}
```

What I am looking for is something sort of like this:
    .(inside|outside) .(inside|outside) {color: blue;}

Comment: `body div:last` may work for you depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: are you looking for `last-child`? Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/kRSJX/)

Comment: Not really related, I understand my initial question was too broad, so I edited it to detail more what I am after.

Comment: .inside, .outside { color: blue; }

Comment: Yes, you can simply use a group selector, using commas

Comment: @HotStuff68 Is it not possible to just apply `color:blue` to the parent..?

Comment: If you're not applying something that's usually inheritable like `color`, you would have to combine both selectors that you already have: `.inside .outside, .outside .inside`. As for a permutation selector, the upcoming specification offers `:matches()` but in cases like this it will only make your selectors unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a group selector, using commas (Blake Mann's comment)

```
.inside, .outside { color: blue; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! So simple once I know how! :)